# The download button is not fetching all df in shiny app

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, tidyverse, shinyapps

I'm trying to build a Shiny app that compares two different reports and brings out the differences.

My problem is that when I click the download button, only the first 2 dataset was found in the Excel workbook that was downloaded (I mean `csw_data` and the `airtel_data`, others were not found).

In the example, I am trying to compare the dataset from the Csw against the Airtel network, in such a way that when the user uploads the Airtel network file and clicks on the Run button for Airtel, all the processes below take place.

Please note that there is a button that when the user clicks, fetches the Cswfile, and it's available for use anytime.

```
# Event handler for Run Airtel button
  observeEvent(input$runAirtelBtn, {
    # Ensure Cswfile is fetched and available before running Airtel
    req(Cswfile())
    
    airtelFile <- input$airtelFile
    
    if (!is.null(airtelFile)) {
      airtel_data(read.csv(airtelFile$datapath, header = FALSE, colClasses = "character"))
      
      # Compare CSW file with Airtel file
      print("Comparing CSW file with Airtel file...")
      Csw_Var <- reactive({
        csw_data <- CSW()
        airtel_data <- Airtel_clean()
        subset(csw_data, !(Confirm.Code %in% airtel_data$V12))
      })
      print("Comparison with CSW file done.")
      
      
      # Compare Airtel file with CSW file
      print("Comparing Airtel file with CSW file...")
      Airtel_Var <- reactive({
        csw_data <- CSW()
        airtel_data <- Airtel_clean()
        subset(airtel_data, !(V12 %in% csw_data$Confirm.Code))
      })
      print("Comparison with CSW file done.")
      
      # Update Csw_Var based on Airtel_Var
      print("Comparing CSW_var with Airtel_var...")
      Csw_Var_updated <- reactive({
        csw_data <- CSW()
        airtel_data <- Airtel_clean()
        
        subset(Csw_Var(), !(Tranx.ID %in% airtel_data$V26))
      })
      print("Comparison with Airtel_var done.")
      
      
      # Update Airtel_Var based on Csw_Var
      print("Comparing Airtel_var with CSW_var...")
      Airtel_Var_updated <- reactive({
        csw_data <- CSW()
        airtel_data <- Airtel_clean()
        merge(Airtel_Var(), Csw_Var(), by.x = "V26", by.y = "Tranx.ID", all.x = TRUE) %>%
          dplyr::select(V10, V12, V13, V16, V18, V20, V22, V23, V26, V32, V33, Status, Merchant, Audit.No, FaceValue) %>%
          dplyr::arrange(desc(Audit.No), na.last = TRUE)
      })
      print("Comparison with Csw_var done.")
      # Perform filtering on Csw_Var_updated
      
      print("Staring all filtered...")
      Wema_Airtel_refund <- reactive({
        Csw_Var_updated() %>%
          dplyr::filter(Merchant == "Wema Bank", Status %in% c("Transaction Declined", "Requery Decline", "Processing"))
      })
      
      Munfat_Airtel_refund <- reactive({
        Csw_Var_updated() %>%
          dplyr::filter(Merchant == "Munfat Innovations Ltd PostPaid", Status %in% c("Transaction Declined", "Requery Declined", "Processing"))
      })
      
      Flutterwave_Airtel_refund <- reactive({
        Csw_Var_updated() %>%
          dplyr::filter(Merchant == "FLUTTERWAVE TECHNOLOGY SOLUTIONS LIMITED", Status %in% c("pending", "Requery Declined", "Processing"))
      })
      
      Ecobank_Airtel_refund <- reactive({
        Csw_Var_updated() %>%
          dplyr::filter(Merchant == "Ecobank", Status %in% c("Transaction Declined", "Requery Declined", "Processing"))
      })
      print("All filtered done.")
      
    } else {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Error",
        "Please upload an Airtel file before running.",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
    }
  })
  
  # Enable download functionality
  observeEvent(input$runAirtelBtn, {
    shinyjs::show("downloadAirtelBtn")
    
    # Perform the comparison with progress update
    withProgress(
      message = "Comparing files...",
      value = 0,
      {
        for (i in 1:100) {
          Sys.sleep(1)  # Simulate processing time
          incProgress(1, detail = paste0(i, "% completion"))
        }
      }
    )
  })
  
  
  output$downloadAirtelBtn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste0("Airtel_Report_", format(Sys.Date() - 1, "%Y-%m-%d"), ".xlsx"),
    content = function(file) {
      # Call the reactive expressions again to ensure the data is up-to-date
      # Call the reactive expressions again to ensure the data is up-to-date
      csw_data <- CSW()
      airtel_data <- Airtel_clean()
      
      
      dataall_airtel <- list(
        "Switch" = csw_data,
        "Airtel" = Airtel_cleaned(),
        "Switch Var" = Csw_Var_data(),
        "Airtel Var" = Airtel_Var_data(),
        "Csw Update" = Csw_Var_updated_data(),
        "Airtel Update" = Airtel_Var_updated_data(),
        "Weda refund" = Weda_Airtel_refund_data(),
        "Mun refund" = Mun_Airtel_refund_data(),
        "cobank refund" = cobank_Airtel_refund_data(),
        "Flutty" = Flutty_Airtel_refund_data()
      
        # Add other data frames here
      )
      
      # Write the list of data frames to the Excel file
      openxlsx::write.xlsx(dataall_airtel, file = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = uiOutput("upload_page"), server = server)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: hi Yomi.blaze93! I just did an edit to make it easier to read (fixed some typos, grammar things, and moved the problem part to the top). If I misunderstood or misrepresented the problem, then feel free to roll back the edit! :-)

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint what is happening with lots of variables not even in the code. Try submitting a Minimal working example instead.
From what I could gather looking at  this code, this line seems suspicious:
`airtel_data(read.csv(airtelFile$datapath, header = FALSE, colClasses = "character"))`

Perhaps airtel_data should be followed by `<- read.csv(...)`, not parentheses?